# Did the ResourceFunction["NewtonCotesWeights"] get corrupted?

Tags: functions, numerical-integration

When using this [*resoure*](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NewtonCotesWeights/), none of the examples are working.

The weights seem to be getting corrupted.

For example, compare the example at the site with these results

```
  f[x_] := x^3 - 5 x^2 + 3 x + 9

  weights = ResourceFunction["NewtonCotesWeights"][6, 0, 5]

  Total[#[[2]]*f[#[[1]]] & /@ weights] // N

  NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

I am using MMA V14, x86 on Windows 10.

**Update** I am not sure what is wrong. I restarted MMA 14 from scratch, still failed. I then tried `ResourceUpdate[ResourceFunction["NewtonCotesWeights"]]`, but it prints a message `"ResourceObject::newest: The most recent version of resource ce832510-0d70-444a-8620-2c219f49e3bf is already downloaded.`

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: MMA 14 WIndows 10 x64. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks @DanielHuber: I will delete and troubleshoot.

Comment: @DanielHuber: I am not sure what is wrong. I restarted MMA 14 from scratch, still failed. I then tried ResourceUpdate[ResourceFunction["NewtonCotesWeights"]], but it prints a message "ResourceObject::newest: The most recent version of resource ce832510-0d70-444a-8620-2c219f49e3bf is already downloaded. Any ideas?

Comment: @Moo I tried it in the cloud and I couldn't reproduce the results in its documentation either.

Comment: @MarcoB: Thanks or verifying that, I found it odd that so far, it was only me, especially since I don't believe I changed anything that would impact such things.